# Incompatible Types (vec4 and vec3) in assignment

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I've been learning OpenGl, along with it "GLSL".
Currently i'm getting an error trying to compile my fragment shader:

> Incompatible types (vec4 and vec3) in assignment (and no available implicit conversion)

Can someone please help me understand and resolve this error?
Code is below:

```
#version 330 core
in vec3 ourColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;

out vec4 color;

// Texture samplers
uniform sampler2D ourTexture1;

void main() {
    // Linearly interpolate between both textures (second texture is only slightly combined)
    color = texture(ourTexture1, TexCoord);
}
```

Thank you.

EDIT:
Here is my shader compiler:

```
class shaders_shader
{
public:
    GLuint Program;
    // Constructor generates the shader on the fly
    shaders_shader( const GLchar *vertexPath, const GLchar *fragmentPath )
    {
    // 1. Retrieve the vertex/fragment source code from filePath
    std::string vertexCode;
    std::string fragmentCode;
    std::ifstream vShaderFile;
    std::ifstream fShaderFile;
    // ensures ifstream objects can throw exceptions:
    vShaderFile.exceptions ( std::ifstream::badbit );
    fShaderFile.exceptions ( std::ifstream::badbit );
    try
    {
        // Open files
        vShaderFile.open( vertexPath );
        fShaderFile.open( fragmentPath );
        std::stringstream vShaderStream, fShaderStream;
        // Read file's buffer contents into streams
        vShaderStream << vShaderFile.rdbuf( );
        fShaderStream << fShaderFile.rdbuf( );
        // close file handlers
        vShaderFile.close( );
        fShaderFile.close( );
        // Convert stream into string
        vertexCode = vShaderStream.str( );
        fragmentCode = fShaderStream.str( );
    }
    catch ( std::ifstream::failure e )
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FILE_NOT_SUCCESFULLY_READ" << std::endl;
    }
    const GLchar *vShaderCode = vertexCode.c_str( );
    const GLchar *fShaderCode = fragmentCode.c_str( );
    // 2. Compile shaders
    GLuint vertex, fragment;
    GLint success;
    GLchar infoLog[512];
    // Vertex Shader
    vertex = glCreateShader( GL_VERTEX_SHADER );
    glShaderSource( vertex, 1, &vShaderCode, NULL );
    glCompileShader( vertex );
    // Print compile errors if any
    glGetShaderiv( vertex, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success );
    if ( !success )
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog( vertex, 512, NULL, infoLog );
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    // Fragment Shader
    fragment = glCreateShader( GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER );
    glShaderSource( fragment, 1, &fShaderCode, NULL );
    glCompileShader( fragment );
    // Print compile errors if any
    glGetShaderiv( fragment, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success );
    if ( !success )
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog( fragment, 512, NULL, infoLog );
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    // Shader Program
    this->Program = glCreateProgram( );
    glAttachShader( this->Program, vertex );
    glAttachShader( this->Program, fragment );
    glLinkProgram( this->Program );
    // Print linking errors if any
    glGetProgramiv( this->Program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success );
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetProgramInfoLog( this->Program, 512, NULL, infoLog );
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    // Delete the shaders as they're linked into our program now and no longer necessery
    glDeleteShader( vertex );
    glDeleteShader( fragment );

}
// Uses the current shader
void Use( )
{
    glUseProgram( this->Program );
}
};
```

Comment: What line does the error point to?

Comment: I’m unsure, the error is prefixed with “0:10” in my log though, if that helps?

Comment: Include the shader loading and compilation code.

Comment: @derhass Edited and included shader loader

Comment: @Plague22 -- *I’m unsure, the error is prefixed with “0:10"* -- So you have no indication the exact line that is giving the error?  Maybe you should be using a better build system, as there is no excuse for not being told the exact line where the error occurs.

Comment: Make sure that you're calling `shaders_shader` with the correct arguments. The shader in the question looks OK.

Comment: What format did you upload the texture as `GL_RGBA` or something else

Comment: @k.krol.27 it’s initialised with GL_RGBA yeah

Comment: Uploaded as and stored as? I should have been clearer earlier sorry

Comment: @k.krol.27 yeah I’ll update the code with a snippet later on

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: That *is* the indication of the line number for the error. String 0, line 10. That's common for GLSL compilers.

Comment: try `color = vec4(texture(ourTexture1, TexCoord).rgb,1.0);`

Comment: @Spektre Thank you, you gorgeous human. Fixed

Comment: @Spektre: Out of curiosity, why does that fix the problem?

Comment: @Plague22 because you defined the `color` as `vec4` and fetching the texture returns `vec3` so you simply convert it to `vec4` by adding the 4th coordinate (which is usually alpha channel for colors). GLSL does not cast automatically so you need to cast the `vec4(vec3,1.0)` manually